# how can i set custom message to sql query for this script

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

got this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($ak) == 0) {
    $sonuc = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($ak) == 1) {
    $sonuc = "you already added";
}
```

this script works succesfully. but mysql_query($sql) echos "1" how can let it echo "successfully added."
thanks...

(im asking simple questions because im new to php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sonuc = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
if($sonuc) {
   echo "successfully added.";
}
```

But as you have `or die(mysql_error())` this is also valid (but easier to mess up with when you change code):

```
$sonuc = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
echo "successfully added.";
```

Comment: kk fixed added ; to end of echo

Comment: Add a semicolon to the end of the echo line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($ak) == 0) {
    $ak = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $sonuc = "successfully added";
}
elseif (mysql_num_rows($ak) == 1) {
    $sonuc = "you already added";
}

echo $sonuc;
```